# How to save facebook birthday_date?

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, facebook-fql

With FQL I get the birthdays in this way:

```
select uid, first_name, last_name, birthday_date from user where uid=me()
```

But then is showed in this format:

```
02/03/1942
```

And if I save it in a DATE field of my mysql database, it save 0000-00-00

How can I save this date in my mysql database ?

Answer (score 2):

Checkout this out- http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create.php

```
<?php
  $test = new DateTime('02/31/2011');
  echo date_format($test, 'Y-m-d H:i:s'); // 2011-03-03 00:00:00
  $test = new DateTime('06/31/2011');
  echo date_format($test, 'Y-m-d H:i:s'); // 2011-07-01 00:00:00
?>
```

You can feed the `DateTime()` constructor a string that is similar to what Facebook returns and then use that object to format the date format that you need.

---

Alternatively, if you want an option consisting only of a MYSQL solution, you could simply pass the original date through `STR_TO_DATE` and feed it the current format. That will format the date for you in the correct way for a `DATE` field type.

```
INSERT INTO  `test` (  `date` ) 
  VALUES (
    STR_TO_DATE(  '02/03/1942',  '%d/%m/%Y' )
  )
```

Check out [the documentation of STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) for more details.